# Formatting Collection with Active Record Serializers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

Total I have the following code:

```
def search
  @regions = Region.search(params[:searchPhrase]).page(params[:current].to_i).per_page(params[:rowCount].to_i)
  data = {
    current: @regions.current_page, 
    rowCount: @regions.per_page,
    total: @regions.count,
    rows: @regions
  }
  respond_with(data)
end
```

This gives me an output like:

```
{total: 20, current: 2, rowCount: 10, rows: [{id: 1, name: "Region"}, ...]}
```

This works fine, but I want the same format all over the application.

I've read some content about ActiveModel Seralizers gem, but I couldn't find a way of doing this the following:

- Addind a root with a custom name. I know I cant set a root with AMS, but how can I name it?
- Adding keys for a CollectionSerializer. I know I can use meta, but I don't want to keys to be under another key. I want the output as it is today.

Does anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `RegionSerializer` like this:

```
class RegionSerializer    
  attributes :current,
             :rowCount,
             :total,
             :regions

  def regions
    # get the regions here
  end
end
```

Then, in your controller, you can have something like this:

```
  def search

    render(
        root: :your_custom_root_name,
        json: rows,
        each_serializer: RegionSerializer
    )
  end

  private

  def rows
    # get collection_of_objects/rows here
  end
```

You can use the `root` option to specify the name of your `root` element and `each_serializer` option to specify the serializer to render your collection of objects as shown above.

Comment: Yes, I can specify root in render (which I'm trying to avoid, so I don't have to do this in all controllers). But in your example, `rows` is not a property of `Region` but is the collection itself.

Comment: I updated my answer. But, what do you really want to achieve? What did you mean by this line: `Addind a root with a custom name. I know I cant set a root with AMS, but how can I name it?` could you please elaborate this a bit?